# Work done by induced electric field in an inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, potential, inductance

Let us say the current in a circuit is increasing at time t=0. This circuit has an inductor (current enters the inductor from left) which opposes this increase in current. I know that the inductor does so by inducing a non-conservative electric field which exists only along the inductor (right?). I also know that this field cannot have a potential associated with it.

What confuses me is the work done by this field. My book says that induced electric fields have an emf which is given by the line integral of the induced electric field along the loop. This 'work' can be treated as the potential drop across the loop. But in case of the inductor, this field is doing some negative work. Now I was taught that emf is the non-electrical work which is responsible for creating a potential difference which drives the current. But in this case the induced field is causing a potential drop across the inductor. How is this possible ?

My reasoning: 
The induced electric field creates a charge seperation essentially converting the inductor to a battery with polarity opposite to the source battery thereby causing a potential drop.

Comment: [Have a look at this lecture given by a Professor at Yale.](https://youtu.be/EYYNRubHIno?t=2266)

Comment: @Farcher the video was helpful. The one thing I could not understand though was the charge accumulation in case of self Induction. Doesn't charge accumulation on inductor terminals mean non-uniform current flow?